# Reinforcement Learning - early exploration problem in hierarchical setting

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

#### Intro

Hi all. I am struggling to understand behavior with two implementations and I was hoping someone might have a clue.
So I have 2 algorithms: HER (RL with a bit of self-supervision) and HAC (hierarchical RL). The environment is picked and place.

#### HAC

A quick summary of how HAC works: two levels (high and low), high level generates a target (x,y,z) where the robot end-effector must be moved. the low level acts on the environment with those targets as goals. high level generates a new target every H steps.

#### Here's my problem

In HER, the first epochs renderings look smooths with slow movements (like deliberate exploration)
In HAC after only 50 iters (1 epoch = 2000 iters) the high-level model always outputs maximum actions (1,1,-1,1). Any idea what could cause this?
After some more training it starts outputting other actions, but most still maximum. It hinders exploration a lot and obviously fails to converge.
To give a comparison, HER converges to >80% accuracy in 40 mins. HAC goes up to 60% (sometimes) in over 48h.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Architecture used is DDPG or TD3 (depending on version I want to use). Here's some code for selecting actions if it helps:

```
mu_v = self.actor(states, goals)
actions = mu_v.data.detach().cpu().numpy()
actions += np.random.normal(0, self.max_action * self.expl_noise, size=actions.shape)
actions = np.clip(actions, self.action_clips[0], self.action_clips[1])
return actions
```

Actor model definition

```
class Actor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_size, goal_size, act_size, action_bounds, offset):
        super(Actor, self).__init__()

        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            # state + goal
            nn.Linear(obs_size + goal_size, HID_SIZE),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(HID_SIZE, HID_SIZE),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(HID_SIZE, HID_SIZE),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(HID_SIZE, act_size),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

        self.action_bounds = nn.Parameter(action_bounds, requires_grad=False)
        self.offset = nn.Parameter(offset, requires_grad=False)

    def forward(self, state, goal):
        return (self.net(torch.cat([state, goal], dim=1)) * self.action_bounds) + self.offset
```

#### Extra

I don't know what other information to add, but I will edit this section as people are asking questions. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add tanh saturation loss. Basically add the L2 norm of the pre-activation output of the actor.

```
actor_loss_v += self.hparams.action_l2 * logits.pow(2).mean()
```